# An issue about the example after [conv.lval#2.2]

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The example is:

```cpp
struct S { int n; };
auto f() {
S x { 1 };
constexpr S y { 2 };
return [&](bool b) { return (b ? y : x).n; };
}
auto g = f();
int m = g(false);   // undefined behavior: access of x.n outside its lifetime
int n = g(true);    // OK, does not access y.n
```

The relevant rule is:

> When an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to an expression E, and either
>
> > 1. E is not potentially evaluated, or
> > 2. the evaluation of E results in the evaluation of a member E<sub>x</sub> of the set of potential results of E, **and E<sub>x</sub> names a variable x that is not odr-used by E<sub>x</sub>([basic.def.odr])**

> the value contained in the referenced object is not accessed.

I doubt with the expression `y.n` which noted as a non odr-used of `n`.

According to the rule:

> The set of potential results of an expression E is defined as follows:
>
> > - If E is an id-expression ([expr.prim.id]), the set contains only E.
> > - [...]
> > - If E is a class member access expression ([expr.ref]) of the form E<sub>1</sub> . template <sub>opt</sub> E<sub>2</sub> naming a **non-static data member**, **the set contains the potential results of E<sub>1</sub>**.

According to bullet 3, the potential result of the expression `y.n` is `y` itself, and `n` is indeed a member of `y` which is the potential result of `y.n`. However, I don't agree with that `n` is not **odr-used**.

According to this rule:
[basic.def.odr#4.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#4.2)

> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression E is odr-used by E unless
>
> > - x is a variable of non-reference type that is usable in constant expressions and has no mutable subobjects, and **E is an element of the set of potential results of an expression of non-volatile-qualified non-class type to which the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion ([conv.lval]) is applied**.

The **lvalue-to-rvalue conversion** is applied to the expression `y.n`, whose potential results only contain the **object expression `y`** rather than `n`. Hence, per [basic.def.odr#4.2], the variable named `n` is odr-used by the expression `n`. So, `g(true)` should be undefined behavior.   How to interpret this example? Is it a wrong example?

Comment: `n` is not contained in set of potential results of `(b ? y : x).n` and thus odr-use simply can't apply to it.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yes, I know that.  what I misunderstand is, the evaluation of E results in the evaluation of **a member Ex of the set of potential results of E**. I thought that a member data of the potential result(y or x) of E.

Comment: And `S::n` is not a variable, after all.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer you mean, since `S::n` is not an object, so it's not the variable per [basic#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#6), Right?

Comment: `s.n` is an object, but `n` still not a variable

Comment: @LanguageLawyer why `n` still not a variable? I don't understand that.  you said  `s.n` is an object, do you mean that  `s` is an object of type `S`? Please interpret such two questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your reasoning is that `[conv.lval]/3.2` *doesn't ask* for `n` to be not-odr-used. The expression in question is `E = (b ? y : x).n`. The set of potential results is `{x, y}`. The evaluation of `E`, when `b = true`, would eventually result in the evaluation of `y`. Therefore, we can set `Ex = y`, and we now find that "the evaluation of `E` results in the evaluation of a member `Ex` of the set of potential results of `E`" is a true statement. The clause now only requires that `Ex = y` names a variable that is not odr-used in `Ex`. Let me repeat that, since I think this is where you went wrong: `[conv.lval]/3.2` asks whether `Ex` odr-uses *itself* (or, really, the variable it names). The thing we're looking for is a proof that the expression `y` does not odr-use the variable `y`. The member access to `n` does not matter.

Well, we continue by looking at `[basic.def.odr]/4`

> A variable `x` whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression `E` is *odr-used* by `E` unless
>
> - ...
> - `x` is a variable of non-reference type that is usable in constant expressions and has no mutable subobjects, and `E` is an element of the set of potential results of an expression of non-volatile-qualified non-class type to which the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (`[conv.lval]`) is applied, or
> - ...

Notice that the `E` here is *not* the `E = (b ? y : x).n` we started with in `[const.lval]/3.2`. `E` is the expression we're testing for odr-use of `y`. Let's name it `E'`. Then `E' = Ex = y`, because, again, we're checking if the expression `y` odr-uses the variable `y`. The first part of the condition holds; `y` is a variable of non-reference type that is usable in constant expressions and it has no mutable subobjects. Now, is `E' = y` an element of the set of potential results to the original `E` (because `E` is the expression of non-volatile-qualified non-class type to which the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied)? Yes, we've gone over that, `y` is one of the potential results of `E`. Therefore, `Ex` does not odr-use `y`. This completes the precondition to `[conv.lval]/3.2`: we now know that `(b ? y : x).n` does not access the value `y.n` when the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is evaluated. Therefore, there is no UB. Again, notice that `n` basically didn't appear at all in our reasoning.

Comment: the set of potential result of `E`( (b ? y : x).n ) is the set of potential results of `(b? x: y)`, per  [basic.def.odr#2.7](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#2.7), which in turn, the potential result are `y` and `x`. So , the set of  potential results of `(b?y:x).n)` is {y,x}, Right? The statement "the evaluation of E results in the evaluation of a member Ex of the set of potential results of E" only requires `x` or `y` is not `odr-used` by the corresponding expression. And according to my understanding for [basic.def.odr#4.2], the variable named y is not odr-used by `y`.